# javascript new Date() isn't updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

```
function doSomething(){
    var rightNow = new Date();
}

doSomething();
```

if my machines' date is 11:59am, after 1min it will be the next day, why am I still seeing it's 3 Jan?

Comment: First it should be 11.59pm. Second are you calling this function once or more than once? Try calling it inside a setTimeout and log rightNow

Comment: What do you see and how? Do you output `rightNow` anywhere?

Comment: As long as you reconstruct a new date, you'll get the current date, otherwise you get the date at construction time. You may alternatively use `Date.now`.

Comment: The timestamp contained in the `Date` object will not change as time passes. It will preserve the one it was originally created with.

Comment: `new Date()` returns a static variable, so assigning the value of `new Date()` to a variable means that the value will **never** change. Try running this if you need some more clarification: `setInterval(function(){alert(Date.now())}, 2500);`

Comment: @Sheerforce what if the whole page refreshed at 12:00 am of 4 jan? then the new Date() should give me 4 jan?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `doSomething()`, you make a new instance of `Date()` right when you call it. It won't change until you call it again. If you want it to change every second, try this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log(new Date);
}, 1000);
```